# Add multiple trackers at once with Transmission Remote

Tags: downloads, bittorrent, transmission, nas, torrent-client

I recently bought a QNap I use as download station, so I switched from downloading files with uTorrent on my PC to downloading them with Transmission on the QNap.

I use Transmission Remote to control downloads from my laptop and smartphone.

Sadly, when I try to add multiple trackers to boost a frozen file, Transmission says me that I added an invalid argument, because it clearly want me to add trackers one by one.

There is a way to add multiple trackers at once, as I did on uTorrent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Edit` button in `Setting > Trackers` and add multiple URLs, each followed by a blank line.

[image: Use the 'Edit' button]

[image: Update the tracker list]

Comment: Sorry, but my interface hasn't any Edit button

Comment: Try updating Transmission to a newer version. My version that has the edit button is 2.8.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding. I don't use Transmission, but Transmission Remote, to download directly on the NAS

Comment: On transmission Remote I only had edit option on a single tracker.... :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem / constraint (not being able to add multiple tracks at once, with copy/paste) into Transmission... until I found a superb, awesome, Transmission client: Transmission Remote GUI. The interface is VERY similar to qBittorrent.
Latest version (as of writing this post) is 5.18.0
By the way, I am connecting to the Transmission app in my Lenovo (former Iomega) NAS (Lenovo-EMC px4-300d)
You can download it from:
https://github.com/transmission-remote-gui/transgui/releases

Hope it is up to your expectations! For me, it is, and even more!
Regards,
Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

To address the OP regarding how to add multiple trackers at-once via "transmission-remote," here are some specific examples with transmission-remote:

The OP only specified using transmission-remote:  For this example, I'm working in BASH.

```
# while read f;do echo "adding tracker $f";transmission-remote -t[#s] -td "$f";done < <(echo -e "tracker.com:1234\ntracker2.com\ntracker1.com/announce\ntracker4.com:333/announce")
```

This will add the trackers provided at the end of the line (in the echo command) which are separated by a "\n" which is important.

If you have a few favorite trackers you add to torrents that don't start or seem stuck you could prep your favorite trackers in a file:

```
mytrackers.txt (file name)
tracker.com:1234
tracker2.com
tracker1.com/announce
tracker4.com:333/announce
```

then use:

```
# while read f;do echo "adding tracker $f";transmission-remote -t[#s] -td "$f";done <mytrackers.txt
```

Important hints & tips:

- You can certainly run the above one-liners without the initial echo (echo "adding tracker $f") but I like the visual verification.
- I would strongly urge you to initially run without the "transmission-remote" command (so you only run with the "echo" line allowing you to verify your trackers as-listed).  The value is if something goes wrong, it's not hitting the transmission-remote command and you see the echo displaying your list of trackers.

Answer (score -1):

Right click and click **Properties > Advanced**

[image: right click menu]

[image: properties]